# phpunit test check statuscode

Tags: php, unit-testing

I'm trying to test my Laravel api with unit testing. But when I try to check for a status code it's not working the way I want it to.

This is my code:

```
public function testExample()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $res = $client->request('POST', 'domain.dev/api/v1/test/1', [
            'form_params' => [
                'currentUserId' => 13
            ]
        ]);  //line 22
        $this->assertEquals(500, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
    }
```

When I try this in for example postman I receive the following:

```
{"result":{"message":"Error show school"}}
```

with status code `500`

If I run phpunit it shows:

`/Users/jamie/Code/domain/tests/ExampleTest.php:22` (see comment for line 22)

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Your call `$res = $client->request(...)` throw an exception.

On [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047844/why-does-phpunit-not-show-any-errors-in-the-console) you can view how to configure php to display this kind of error correctly.