# php(unit) not displaying error output in docker container

Tags: php, bash, error-handling, docker, phpunit

I recognize this is likely a php configuration issue and not docker or phpunit, but I wanted to be clear about the different moving pieces.

I have a docker container with the following Dockerfile

```
FROM php:5.6-cli
COPY . /spider
WORKDIR /spider

RUN pecl install xdebug
RUN docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer
```

When I run that container for bash using (`docker run -it my_php bash`) I can verify that php and xdebug are installed correctly.

When I try to run `vendor/bin/phpunit`, the tests begin, run into an error, and then the process simply dies with no error output. Failed tests show failures and passed tests show green.

Following [Why does phpunit not show any errors in the console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18047844/why-does-phpunit-not-show-any-errors-in-the-console), I have added

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); // or error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

to the tests `bootstrap.php` file AND

```
<ini name="display_errors" value="On" />
<ini name="display_startup_errors" value="On" />
```

to the phpunit.xml.dist file (redundant, I know).

When I run `php -i` it actually says there is no `php.ini` file

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /usr/local/etc/php
Loaded Configuration File => (none)
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed => /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-php-ext-xdebug.ini
```

I am happy to post any other logs or the entire contents of the `php -i` output.

Thanks for the help!