# How to make PHPUnit output errors?

Tags: php, error-handling, phpunit, output, echo

I'm running PHPUnit from the command line in windows as follows:

```
 php phpunit.phar --bootstrap .\commonTests\bootstrap_local.php .\commonTests\DIContainerTest.php --testdox --stderr -v
```

and I'm getting this result:

> PHPUnit 10.1.2 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
>
> Runtime:       PHP 8.2.0
>
> E
>
> Time: 00:00.004, Memory: 24.00 MB
>
> ERRORS! Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

How do I make it output the error messages? As you can see I've tried a number of flags but it's still leaving me in the dark. I've also tried `--verbose` and `--debug` but it says neither of those are supported

I tried creating a file phpunit.xml where I run the test:

```
<phpunit>
    <php>
        <ini name="error_reporting" value="E_ALL" />
        <ini name="display_errors" value="1" />
        <ini name="display_startup_errors" value="1" />
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

But it had no effect.

I also tried adding this to the beginning of the Test class file:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
```

But it had no effect either.

Please help!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the only option is to remove the `--testdox` flag.